# Does "Find-Replace whole word only" exist in python?

Tags: python, regex

Does "Find-Replace whole word only" exist in python?

e.g. "old string oldstring boldstring bold"
if i want to replace 'old' with 'new', new string should look like,

"new string oldstring boldstring bold"

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 44):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "old string oldstring boldstring bold"
>>> re.sub(r'\bold\b', 'new', s)
'new string oldstring boldstring bold'
```

This is done by using [**word boundaries**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Needless to say, this regex is not Python-specific and is implemented in most regex engines.

Answer (score 5):

you need the following regex:

```
\bold\b
```