# Replace Pattern matching portion with some other value in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to replace ROAD with RD

```
addr = ['100 NORTH MAIN ROAD',
            '100 BROAD ROAD APT.',
            'SAROJINI DEVI ROAD',
            'BROAD AVENUE ROAD']
```

Output

```
output : ['100 NORTH MAIN RD.',
            '100 BROAD RD. APT.',
            'SAROJINI DEVI RD.',
            'BROAD AVENUE RD.']
```

i tried below mentioned code

```
new_address=[word.replace("ROAD","RD") for word in addr]
```

but not getting desired output (BROAD is also getting replaces by RD.)

```
['100 NORTH MAIN RD.', '100 BRD. RD. APT.', 'SAROJINI DEVIRD.', 'BRD. AVENUE RD.']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does "Find-Replace whole word only" exist in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658215/does-find-replace-whole-word-only-exist-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

In this current example can do:

```
new_address=[word.replace(" ROAD"," RD.") for word in addr]
```

Or in general sence, use `regex`:

```
new_address = [re.sub(r'\bROAD\b', 'RD.', w) for w in l]

# ['100 NORTH MAIN RD.', '100 BROAD RD. APT.', 'SAROJINI DEVI RD.', 
#   'BROAD AVENUE RD.']
```

Comment: Hi thanks for a reply ,can we achieve this using regex.