# How to remove a corresponding word in a dictionary from a string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a text:

{"love":1, "expect":2, "annoy":-2}

test="i love you, that is annoying"

I need to remove the words from the string if they appear in the dictionary. I have tried this code:

```
for k in dict:
    if k in test:
        test=test.replace(k, "")
```

However the result is:

i  you,that is ing

And this is not what I am looking for, as it should not remove "annoy" as a part of the word, the whole word should be evaluated. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "Find-Replace whole word only" exist in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658215/does-find-replace-whole-word-only-exist-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not assign names to variables that are also names of builtin in classes, such as `dict`.

Variable `test` is a string composed of characters. When you say, `if k in test:`, you will be testing `k` to see if it is a substring of `test`. What you want to do is break up `test` into a list of words and compare `k` against each complete word in that list. If words are separated by a single space, then they may be "split" with:

`test`.split(' ')

The only complication is that it will create the following list:

```
['i', '', 'you,', 'that', 'is', 'annoying']
```

Note that the third item still has a `,` in it. So we should first get rid of punctuation marks we might expect to find in our sentence:

```
test.replace('.', '').replace(',', ' ').split(' ')
```

Yielding:

```
['i', '', 'you', '', 'that', 'is', 'annoying']
```

The following will actually get rid of all punctuation:

```
import string
test.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

So now our code becomes:

```
>>> import string
>>> d = {"love":1, "expect":2, "annoy":-2}
>>> test="i love you, that is annoying"
>>> for k in d:
...     if k in test.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).split(' '):
...         test=test.replace(k, "")
...
>>> print(test)
i  you, that is annoying
>>>
```

You may now find you have extra spaces in your sentence, but you can figure out how to get rid of those.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude all punctuations at once rather than using multiple `.replace()`?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Yes, using `import string; test.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))`

Comment: That would make more sense to use if we have a long string which we do not know specifics of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
query = "i love you, that is annoying"
query = query.replace('.', '').replace(',', '')
my_dict = {"love": 1, "expect": 2, "annoy": -2}
querywords = query.split()

resultwords = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in my_dict]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)

print(result)
>> 'i you, that is annoying'
```

If you want to exclude all words without being key sensitive convert all keys in `my_dict` to lowercase:

```
my_dict = {k.lower(): v for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: You get rid of punctuation but you never put it back. So I don't see how you end up with the final print string you show. Something is amiss here.

Comment: Yes, missed that one, thank you. In your example, which code part places the punctuation back?

Comment: I never take the punctuation out of the original string. I am doing the `replace` on the original string, *not* on the list of words formed from the original string after punctuation is removed and split.